# how to display a full length on json object in the .replace() function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, replace

I have a problem with an array of jSON. I am trying to get to the point of displaying the whole array. I am able to see it in the console, but when I am doing exactly the same in the :

> .replace("{ingredients}", d.ingredientName);

I am getting to the point of undefined. 
I don't want to get to the point of making it this way:

> .replace("{ingredients}", d[0].ingredientName);

and ect.

```
var i = '<?php echo json_encode($json) ?>';
var b = JSON.parse(i);
var c = '<?php echo json_encode($jObj) ?>';
var d = JSON.parse(c);
console.log(d);

var t = '<div class="col-lg-12">\
<h1>{name}</h1>\
   <img class="col-lg-6" src="{photo}" alt="img">\
     <div class="caption">\
       <h4>{ingredients}</h4>\
        <h4>{description}</h4>\
   </div>\
</div>';

var tu = t.replace("{photo}", b[0].photo)
.replace("{name}", b[0].recipeName)
.replace("{description}", b[0].recipeDescription)
.replace("{ingredients}", d.ingredientName);

$(".pcontainer").append(tu);
```

This is the array of json I am trying to display:

> [{"ingredientName":"milk"},{"ingredientName":"phad thai
>   sauce"},{"ingredientName":"rice noodles"}]

Comment: Please edit your post to contain sample values for `$json` and `$jObj`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop to add each ingredient to a new string and then replace {ingrediens} with that string.

For example:

```js
var listOfIngredientsHTML = "";

for (ingredient of d) {
  if (listOfIngredientsHTML.length === 0) {
    listOfIngredientsHTML += "," + ingredientName
  } else {
    listOfIngredientsHTML += ingredientName
  }
}

var tu = t.replace("{photo}", b[0].photo)
.replace("{name}", b[0].recipeName)
.replace("{description}", b[0].recipeDescription)
.replace("{ingredients}", listOfIngredients);
```